$a_n \to \infty$ and $b_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, $ \lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{a_{n_j + M}}{b_{n_j + M}} = 1, $ so hold for $M=0$?
Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be sequences such that $a_n \to \infty$ and $b_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Moreover, assume that $b_{n_j}$ is a monotonic sequence for all $j \geq 1$.
Given that
$$
\lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{a_{n_j + M}}{b_{n_j + M}} = 1,
$$
for a fixed shift $M \in \mathbb{Z}$, can we conclude that
$$
\lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{a_{n_j}}{b_{n_j}} = 1?
$$
